# Output colMeans in columns rather than rows

Tags: r

When I use the colMeans function on a dataset, R outputs the means into rows rather than the original column format. Here is an example:

```
Year J F M A M J J A S O N D
1851 4 6 3 6 9 7 1 2 8 9 5 0 
1852 3 8 5 5 5 3 2 8 6 7 4 2
1853 5 7 4 8 6 9 4 4 4 2 1 2
```

When I use the function

```
colMeans(df)
```

The output is returned as:

```
Year Mean
J     4
F     7
M     4
A     6
etc...
```

How can I develop the script to ensure the output is organised in columns like the original data rather than rows? It should look like:

```
J F M A M J J A S O N D
4 7 4 6 etc............
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of the data.  Is it a data.frame or matrix.  If it is a data.frame or matrix, it should return the output in the expected one you showed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering input as

```
dft <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Year J F M A M J J A S O N D
1851 4 6 3 6 9 7 1 2 8 9 5 0 
1852 3 8 5 5 5 3 2 8 6 7 4 2
1853 5 7 4 8 6 9 4 4 4 2 1 2",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

you could try

```
t(round(colMeans(dft),0))
```

which gives

```
     Year J F M A M.1 J.1 J.2 A.1 S O N D
[1,] 1852 4 7 4 6   7   6   2   5 6 6 3 1
```

and then get rid of the `Year` field if you want to.